# "errorMessage": "'queryStringParameters'", "errorType": "KeyError",

Tags: python, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

> ```
> # import json
>
> # print('Loading Clinsj functions')
>
> # def lambda_handler(event, context):
> #     print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event,indent=2))
> #     return {"message":"Hello from Clinsj!"}
> import json
> # import boto3
> # from flask_lambda import FlaskLambda
> # from flask import request
> # app = FlaskLambda(__name__)
>
> # ddb=boto3.resource('dynamodb')
> # table=dob.Table('clinsj-api2')
>
>
> # @app.route("/", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
> # def calculate_total_income():
> def lambda_handler(event,context):
>     total = ''
>     T_T_I = ''
>     W_C_I = ''
>     T_B = ''
>     T_F_I = ''
>     C_T = ''
>     S_A_T = ''
>     H_C = ''
>     S_A_C = ''
>     W_C_I_C = ''
>     T_D_C = ''
>     T_E_L = ''
>     Score = ''
>     Score_2 = ''
>     Score_3 = ''
>     Knockout_11 = ''
>     Knockout_22 = ''
>     Knockout_33 = ''
>     Knockout_44 = ''
>     Knockout_55 = ''
>     Knockout_66 = ''
>     Factor = ''
>     WT_score11 = ''
>     ET_score11 = ''
>     TI_score11 = ''
>     WT_score22 = ''
>     ET_score22 = ''
>     TI_score22 = ''
>     Score_of_PB1 = ''
>     Score_of_SB1 = ''
>     TOS = ''
>     Anyknock_outs1 = ''
>     Set_score_to_zero1 = ''
>     Speedometer1 = ''
>     Age_Score1 = ''
>     Age_Score2 = ''
>
>     # if request.method == 'POST' and 'salary/wages' in request.form and 'other salary/wages' in request.form and
> ```
>
> 'tax_free_rental_income' in request.form and 'other_tax_free_income'
> in request.form:
> # Salary_or_wages = int(request.form.get('salary/wages'))
> # Other_salary_wages = int(request.form.get('other salary/wages'))
> # Tax_free_rental_income = int(
> #     request.form.get('tax_free_rental_income'))
> # Other_tax_free_income = int(request.form.get('other_tax_free_income'))
> # total = Salary_or_wages + Other_salary_wages + 
> #     Tax_free_rental_income + Other_tax_free_income
>
> ```
>     Salary_or_wages = event["queryStringParameters"]['salary/wages']
>     Other_salary_wages = event["queryStringParameters"]['other salary/wages']
>     Tax_free_rental_income = event["queryStringParameters"]['tax_free_rental_income']
>     Other_tax_free_income = event["queryStringParameters"]['other_tax_free_income']
>     total = int(Salary_or_wages) + int(Other_salary_wages) + int(Tax_free_rental_income) + int(Other_tax_free_income)
>
> # calculate_total_debts():
>     Total_Debt = ''
>     # if request.method == 'POST' and 'car_loans' in request.form and 'credit_card' in request.form and 'student_loans' in request.form
> ```
>
> and 'mortgage_loans' in request.form:
> #     Car_Loans = int(request.form.get('car_loans'))
> #     Credit_Cards = int(request.form.get('credit_card'))
> #     Student_Loans = int(
> #         request.form.get('student_loans'))
> #     Mortgage_Loans = int(request.form.get('mortgage_loans'))
> #     Total_Debt = Car_Loans + Credit_Cards + 
> #         Student_Loans + Mortgage_Loans
> Car_Loans = event["queryStringParameters"]['car_loans']
> Credit_Cards = event["queryStringParameters"]['credit_card']
> Student_Loans = event["queryStringParameters"]['student_loans']
> Mortgage_Loans = event["queryStringParameters"]['mortgage_loans']
> Total_Debt = int(Car_Loans) + int(Credit_Cards) + int(Student_Loans) + int(Mortgage_Loans)
>
> ```
> # Existing rate and Worst case rate():
>     E_Rate = ''
>     WC_Rate = ''
>     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'existing_rate' in request.form and 'worst_case_rate' in request.form:
>     #     Existing_Rate = int(request.form.get('existing_rate'))
>     #     Wrost_Case_Rate = 5
>     #     E_Rate = Existing_Rate
>     #     WC_Rate = Existing_Rate + Wrost_Case_Rate
>     Existing_Rate = event["queryStringParameters"]['existing_rate']
>     Wrost_Case_Rate = 5
>     E_Rate = Existing_Rate
>     WC_Rate = int(Existing_Rate) + int(Wrost_Case_Rate)
>
> # calculate_total_security():
>     total2 = ''
>     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'secured_in_property' in request.form and 'other_security' in request.form:
>     #     Secured_In_Property = int(request.form.get('secured_in_property'))
>     #     Other_Security = int(request.form.get('other_security'))
>     #     total2 = Secured_In_Property + Other_Security
>     Secured_In_Property = event["queryStringParameters"]['secured_in_property']
>     Other_Security = event["queryStringParameters"]['other_security']
>     total2 = int(Secured_In_Property) + int(Other_Security)
>
> # house_located_in_oslo and primary_residence():
>     HLIO = ''
>     PR = ''
>     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'house_located_in_oslo' in request.form or 'primary_residence' in request.form:
>     #     House_Located_In_Oslo = str(request.form.get('house_located_in_oslo'))
>     #     Primary_Residence = str(request.form.get('primary_residence'))
>     #     HLIO = House_Located_In_Oslo
>     #     PR = Primary_Residence
>     House_Located_In_Oslo = event["queryStringParameters"]['house_located_in_oslo']
>     Primary_Residence = event["queryStringParameters"]['primary_residence']
>     HLIO = House_Located_In_Oslo
>     PR = Primary_Residence
> # calculate_annual_household_cost():
>     total3 = ''
>     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'number_of_adults' in request.form or 'number_of_childerns' in request.form and
> ```
>
> 'number_of_cars' in request.form:
> #     Number_Of_Adults = int(request.form.get('number_of_adults'))
> #     Number_Of_Childerns = int(request.form.get('number_of_childerns'))
> #     Number_Of_Cars = int(request.form.get('number_of_cars'))
> #     Other_Household_spend = (
> #         Number_Of_Adults + Number_Of_Childerns)*393 + int(2590) + Number_Of_Cars * 2608
>
> ```
>     #     total3 = (Number_Of_Adults * 7500 + Number_Of_Childerns *
>     #               5500 + Other_Household_spend) * 12
>     Number_Of_Adults = event["queryStringParameters"]['number_of_adults']
>     Number_Of_Childerns = event["queryStringParameters"]['number_of_childerns']
>     Number_Of_Cars = event["queryStringParameters"]['number_of_cars']
>     Other_Household_spend = (int(Number_Of_Adults) + int(Number_Of_Childerns))*393 + int(2590) + int(Number_Of_Cars) * 2608
>     total3 = (int(Number_Of_Adults) * 7500 + int(Number_Of_Childerns) *5500 + int(Other_Household_spend)) * 12
>
> #     d = date.today().day
> #     m = date.today().month
> #     y = date.today().year
> # # Primary_Borrower():
> #     DOB1 = ''
> #     WT1 = ''
> #     ET1 = ''
> #     TI1 = ''
> #     age1 = ''
> #     Day11 = ''
> #     Month11 = ''
> #     Year11 = ''
> #     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'date_of_birth1' in request.form or 'worktype1' in request.form and 'employer_type1' in
> ```
>
> request.form and 'total_income1' in request.form:
> #     # if request.method == 'POST' or 'day1' in request.form or 'month1' in request.form or 'year1' in request.form or 'worktype1' in
> request.form and 'employer_type1' in request.form and 'total_income1'
> in request.form:
> #     #     Day1 = int(request.form.get('day1'))
> #     #     Month1 = int(request.form.get('month1'))
> #     #     Year1 = int(request.form.get('year1'))
> #     #     Day11 = Day1
> #     #     Month11 = Month1
> #     #     Year11 = Year1
> #     Day1 = event["queryStringParameters"]['day1']
> #     Month1 = event["queryStringParameters"]['month1']
> #     Year1 = event["queryStringParameters"]['year1']
> #     Day11 = int(Day1)
> #     Month11 = int(Month1)
> #     Year11 = int(Year1)
> #         if Day1 > d and Month1 >= m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy = (y-1) - Year1
> #             age1 = int(yy)
> #         elif Day1 > d and Month1 < m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy = y - Year1
> #             age1 = int(yy)
> #         elif Day1 < d and Month1 > m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy = (y-1) - Year1
> #             age1 = int(yy)
> #         else:
> #             yy = y - Year1
> #             age1 = int(yy)
>
> ```
> #         # Age score calculation for PB
> #         if age1 < 30:
> #             Age_Score = 0
> #             Age_Score1 = Age_Score
> #         elif age1 < 50:
> #             Age_Score = 20
> #             Age_Score1 = Age_Score
> #         elif age1 < 60:
> #             Age_Score = -10
> #             Age_Score1 = Age_Score
> #         elif age1 < 110:
> #             Age_Score = 0
> #             Age_Score1 = Age_Score
>
> #         # Wt score calculation:
> #         Worktype = str(request.form.get('worktype1'))
> #         if Worktype == "Fixed":
> #             WT_score1 = 20
> #             WT_score11 = WT_score1
> #         else:
> #             WT_score1 = 0
> #             WT_score11 = WT_score1
>
> #         Employer_Type = str(request.form.get('employer_type1'))
> #         if Employer_Type == "Public Sector":
> #             ET_score1 = 20
> #             ET_score11 = ET_score1
> #         else:
> #             ET_score1 = 0
> #             ET_score11 = ET_score1
>
> #         # TI score calculation:
> #         Total_Income = int(request.form.get('total_income1'))
> #         if Total_Income < 500000:
> #             TI_score1 = 0
> #             TI_score11 = TI_score1
> #         elif Total_Income < 700000:
> #             TI_score1 = 20
> #             TI_score11 = TI_score1
> #         elif Total_Income < 900000:
> #             TI_score1 = 50
> #             TI_score11 = TI_score1
> #         elif Total_Income < 1100000:
> #             TI_score1 = 100
> #             TI_score11 = TI_score1
>
> #         # DOB1 = Date_Of_Birth
> #         WT1 = Worktype
> #         ET1 = Employer_Type
> #         TI1 = Total_Income
> #         # Other Elements - attractiveness of customer
>
>
> # # Secondary_Borrower():
> #     DOB2 = ''
> #     WT2 = ''
> #     ET2 = ''
> #     TI2 = ''
> #     age2 = ''
> #     Day22 = ''
> #     Month22 = ''
> #     Year22 = ''
> #     if request.method == 'POST' or 'date_of_birth2' in request.form or 'worktype2' in request.form and 'employer_type2' in
> ```
>
> request.form and 'total_income2' in request.form:
> #         # Date_Of_Birth2 = date(request.form.get(int('date_of_birth2')))
> #         Day2 = event["queryStringParameters"]['day12']
> #         Month2 = event["queryStringParameters"]['month2']
> #         Year2 = event["queryStringParameters"]['year2']
> #         Day22 = Day2
> #         Month22 = Month2
> #         Year22 = Year2
> #         if Day2 > d and Month2 >= m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy2 = (y-1) - Year2
> #             age2 = int(yy2)
> #         elif Day2 > d and Month2 < m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy2 = y - Year2
> #             age2 = int(yy2)
> #         elif Day2 < d and Month2 > m:
> #             # dd = (d+30)- Day1
> #             # mm = ((m - 1) + 12) - Month1
> #             yy2 = (y-1) - Year2
> #             age2 = int(yy2)
> #         else:
> #             yy2 = y - Year2
> #             age2 = int(yy2)
>
> ```
> #         # Age score calculation for SB
> #         if age2 < 30:
> #             Age_Score_2 = 0
> #             Age_Score2 = Age_Score_2
> #         elif age2 < 50:
> #             Age_Score_2 = 20
> #             Age_Score2 = Age_Score_2
> #         elif age2 < 60:
> #             Age_Score_2 = -10
> #             Age_Score2 = Age_Score_2
> #         elif age2 < 110:
> #             Age_Score_2 = 0
> #             Age_Score2 = Age_Score_2
> #         # age_2 = d - Year2 - ((m, d) < (Month2, Day2))
> #         # age2 = age_2
> #         # today = date.today()
> #         # age_2 = today.year - Date_Of_Birth2.year - \
> #         #     ((today.month, today.day) < (Date_Of_Birth2.month, Date_Of_Birth2.day))
> #         # age2 = age_2
> #         # Date_Of_Birth2.year
> #         # particular_date = datetime(request.form.get('date_of_birth2'))
> #         # new_date = datetime.today() - particular_date
> #         # age=new_date.days
> #         Worktype2 = str(request.form.get('worktype2'))
> #         if Worktype2 == "Fixed":
> #             WT_score2 = 20
> #             WT_score22 = WT_score2
> #         else:
> #             WT_score2 = 0
> #             WT_score22 = WT_score2
>
> #         Employer_Type2 = str(request.form.get('employer_type2'))
> #         if Employer_Type2 == "Public Sector":
> #             ET_score2 = 20
> #             ET_score22 = ET_score2
> #         else:
> #             ET_score2 = 0
> #             ET_score22 = ET_score2
>
> #         Total_Income2 = int(request.form.get('total_income2'))
> #         if Total_Income2 < 500000:
> #             TI_score2 = 0
> #             TI_score22 = TI_score2
> #         elif Total_Income2 < 700000:
> #             TI_score2 = 20
> #             TI_score22 = TI_score2
> #         elif Total_Income2 < 900000:
> #             TI_score2 = 50
> #             TI_score22 = TI_score2
> #         elif Total_Income2 < 1100000:
> #             TI_score2 = 100
> #             TI_score22 = TI_score2
>
> #         # DOB2 = Date_Of_Birth2
> #         WT2 = Worktype2
> #         ET2 = Employer_Type2
> #         TI2 = Total_Income2
>
>         # Total Score of Other Elements - attractiveness of customer
>         # Score of primary borrower
>         # Score_of_PB = WT_score1+ET_score1+TI_score1+Age_Score1
>         # Score_of_PB1 = Score_of_PB
>         # Score of Secondary borrower
>         # Score_of_SB = WT_score2+ET_score2+TI_score22+Age_Score2
>         # Score_of_SB1 = Score_of_SB
>         # Qualifying - ability to pay worst case rates
>
>         # Total taxable income
>     Total_Taxable_Income = Salary_or_wages + Other_salary_wages
>     T_T_I = Total_Taxable_Income
>
>     # Worst case interest:
>     Wrost_Case_Interest = (Total_Debt * (WC_Rate/100))
>     W_C_I = Wrost_Case_Interest
>
>     if(W_C_I < 25):
>         Score = 0
>         Knockout_1 = 'True'
>         Knockout_11 = Knockout_1
>         Knockscore = 0
>     elif(W_C_I >= 25 and W_C_I < 50):
>         Score = 250
>         Knockout_2 = 'False'
>         Knockout_22 = Knockout_2
>         Knockscore = 0
>     elif(W_C_I >= 50 and W_C_I < 75):
>         Score = 260
>         Knockout_2 = 'False'
>         Knockout_22 = Knockout_2
>         Knockscore = 0
>     elif(W_C_I >= 75 and W_C_I < 100):
>         Score = 270
>         Knockout_2 = 'False'
>         Knockout_22 = Knockout_2
>         Knockscore = 0
>     elif (W_C_I >= 100):
>         Score = 300
>         Knockout_2 = 'False'
>         Knockout_22 = Knockout_2
>         Knockscore = 0
>     # Taxable_Base
>     Taxable_Base = Total_Taxable_Income - Wrost_Case_Interest
>     T_B = Taxable_Base
>
>     # Calculated_Tax
>     Calculated_Tax = round((T_B*0.4054)-62000)
>     C_T = Calculated_Tax
>
>     # Tax_free_income
>     Tax_Free_Income = Tax_free_rental_income + Other_tax_free_income
>     T_F_I = Tax_Free_Income
>
>     # Surplus After Tax
>     Surplus_After_Tax = Total_Taxable_Income - \
>         Wrost_Case_Interest - Calculated_Tax + Tax_Free_Income
>     S_A_T = Surplus_After_Tax
>
>     # Household Cost
>     Household_Cost = total3
>     H_C = Household_Cost
>
>     # Surplus After Costs
>     Surplus_After_Costs = S_A_T - H_C
>     S_A_C = Surplus_After_Costs
>
>     # Worst case interest cover:
>     Worst_Case_Interest_Cover = round(-(S_A_C / -W_C_I)*100)
>     W_C_I_C = Worst_Case_Interest_Cover
>
>     # Qualifying - total debt cover
>     Total_Debt_Cover = round((Total_Debt / total), 2)
>     T_D_C = (Total_Debt_Cover)
>     if(T_D_C >= 4.00):
>         Score_2 = 0
>         Knockout_3 = 'True'
>         Knockout_33 = Knockout_3
>         Knockscore2 = 1
>     elif(T_D_C > 3.50 and T_D_C <= 4.00):
>         Score_2 = 250
>         Knockout_4 = 'False'
>         Knockout_44 = Knockout_4
>         Knockscore2 = 0
>     elif(T_D_C > 2.50 and T_D_C <= 3.50):
>         Score_2 = 260
>         Knockout_4 = 'False'
>         Knockout_44 = Knockout_4
>         Knockscore2 = 0
>     elif(T_D_C > 2.00 and T_D_C <= 2.50):
>         Score_2 = 270
>         Knockout_4 = 'False'
>         Knockout_44 = Knockout_4
>         Knockscore2 = 0
>     elif (T_D_C <= 2.00):
>         Score_2 = 300
>         Knockout_4 = 'False'
>         Knockout_44 = Knockout_4
>         Knockscore2 = 0
>
>     # Qualifying - Equity levels
>     Total_Equity_Level = round((1-(Total_Debt/total2))*100)
>     T_E_L = Total_Equity_Level
>     if(T_E_L < 15):
>         Score_3 = 0
>         Knockout_5 = 'True'
>         Knockout_55 = Knockout_5
>         Knockscore3 = 1
>     elif(T_E_L >= 15 and T_E_L < 30):
>         Score_3 = 100
>         Knockout_6 = 'False'
>         Knockout_66 = Knockout_6
>         Knockscore3 = 0
>     elif(T_E_L >= 30 and T_E_L < 50):
>         Score_3 = 150
>         Knockout_6 = 'False'
>         Knockout_66 = Knockout_6
>         Knockscore3 = 0
>     elif(T_E_L >= 50 and T_E_L < 100):
>         Score_3 = 230
>         Knockout_6 = 'False'
>         Knockout_66 = Knockout_6
>         Knockscore3 = 0
>     elif (T_E_L >= 100):
>         Score_3 = 300
>         Knockout_6 = 'False'
>         Knockout_66 = Knockout_6
>         Knockscore3 = 0
>
>     # Total_Overall_Score
>     Total_Overall_Score = Score + Score_2 + Score_3 + Score_of_PB1 + Score_of_SB1
>     TOS = Total_Overall_Score
>
>     # Any knock outs - e.g. where they are below minimum regulatory:
>     if(Knockscore and Knockscore2 and Knockscore3 == 0):
>         Anyknock_outs = 0
>         Anyknock_outs1 = Anyknock_outs
>     else:
>         Anyknock_outs = Knockscore + Knockscore2 + Knockscore3
>
>     # If there was a knock out - set score to zero:
>     if(Anyknock_outs > 0):
>         Set_score_to_zero = 0
>         Set_score_to_zero1 = Set_score_to_zero
>     else:
>         Set_score_to_zero = Total_Overall_Score
>         Set_score_to_zero1 = Set_score_to_zero
>
>     # Current rate assesment(Factor):
>     if(E_Rate < 1.50):
>         Score_4 = 10
>         Factor = Score_4
>     elif(E_Rate >= 1.5 and E_Rate < 1.75):
>         Score_4 = 25
>         Factor = Score_4
>     elif(E_Rate >= 1.75 and E_Rate < 2.0):
>         Score_4 = 50
>         Factor = Score_4
>     elif(E_Rate >= 2.0 and E_Rate < 3.0):
>         Score_4 = 75
>         Factor = Score_4
>     elif (E_Rate >= 3.0):
>         Score_4 = 100
>         Factor = Score_4
>
>     # Speedometer:
>     Speedometer = (Score_4/100) * Total_Overall_Score
>     Speedometer1 = Speedometer
>
>     # return render_template("index.html", Age_Score11=Age_Score1, Age_Score22=Age_Score2, Day_1=Day11, Month_1=Month11, Year_1=Year11,
> ```
>
> Day_2=Day22, Month_2=Month22, Year_2=Year22, age11=age1, age22=age2,
> Speedometer11=Speedometer1, Set_score_to_zero11=Set_score_to_zero1,
> Anyknock_outs11=Anyknock_outs1, TOS1=TOS, Score_of_PB11=Score_of_PB1,
> Score_of_SB11=Score_of_SB1, WT_score_1=WT_score11,
> ET_score_1=ET_score11, TI_score_1=TI_score11, WT_score_2=WT_score22,
> ET_score_2=ET_score22, TI_score_2=TI_score22, Score1=Score,
> Knockout_1=Knockout_11, Knockout_2=Knockout_22, Score2=Score_2,
> Knockout_3=Knockout_33, Knockout_4=Knockout_44, Score3=Score_3,
> Knockout_5=Knockout_55, Knockout_6=Knockout_66, Factor_1=Factor,
> total_income=total, total_debts=Total_Debt, total_security=total2,
> annual_household_cost=total3,  output_wt1=WT1, output_et1=ET1,
> output_ti1=TI1, output_wt2=WT2, output_et2=ET2, output_ti2=TI2,
> hlio=HLIO, pr=PR, ER=E_Rate, WCR=WC_Rate, TTI=T_T_I, WCI=W_C_I,
> TB=T_B, TFI=T_F_I, CT=C_T, SAT=S_A_T, HC=H_C, SAC=S_A_C, WCIC=W_C_I_C,
> TDC=T_D_C, TEL=T_E_L)
> # output_dob1=DOB1,  output_dob2=DOB2,
>
> ```
> # if __name__ == '__main__':
> #     app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port=80, debug=True,)
>     response["headers"] = event["headers"]
>
>     return (
>         json.dumps(Age_Score11=Age_Score1, Age_Score22=Age_Score2, Day_1=Day11, Month_1=Month11, Year_1=Year11, Day_2=Day22,
> ```
>
> Month_2=Month22, Year_2=Year22, age11=age1, age22=age2,
> Speedometer11=Speedometer1, Set_score_to_zero11=Set_score_to_zero1,
> Anyknock_outs11=Anyknock_outs1, TOS1=TOS, Score_of_PB11=Score_of_PB1,
> Score_of_SB11=Score_of_SB1, WT_score_1=WT_score11,
> ET_score_1=ET_score11, TI_score_1=TI_score11, WT_score_2=WT_score22,
> ET_score_2=ET_score22, TI_score_2=TI_score22, Score1=Score,
> Knockout_1=Knockout_11,
> Knockout_2=Knockout_22, Score2=Score_2, Knockout_3=Knockout_33, Knockout_4=Knockout_44, Score3=Score_3,
> Knockout_5=Knockout_55, Knockout_6=Knockout_66, Factor_1=Factor,
> total_income=total, total_debts=Total_Debt, total_security=total2,
> annual_household_cost=total3,  output_wt1=WT1, output_et1=ET1,
> output_ti1=TI1, output_wt2=WT2, output_et2=ET2, output_ti2=TI2,
> hlio=HLIO, pr=PR, ER=E_Rate, WCR=WC_Rate, TTI=T_T_I, WCI=W_C_I,
> TB=T_B, TFI=T_F_I, CT=C_T, SAT=S_A_T, HC=H_C, SAC=S_A_C, WCIC=W_C_I_C,
> TDC=T_D_C, TEL=T_E_L),
> 200,
> {'Content-Type': "application/json"}
> )

#the error im getting is :
Test Event Name
test

Response
{
"errorMessage": "'queryStringParameters'",
"errorType": "KeyError",
"stackTrace": [
"  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 67, in lambda_handler\n    Salary_or_wages = event["queryStringParameters"]['salary/wages']\n"
]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 0c3fcadc-3967-4381-b176-1ec50045b28c Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] KeyError: 'queryStringParameters'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 67, in lambda_handler
    Salary_or_wages = event["queryStringParameters"]['salary/wages']

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with that code. I suspect that your *event* object (dictionary) is incorrectly structured

Comment: then what to do that ? and here is my actual code :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

is your API gateway set up as a Proxy Lambda Integration or a Lambda Integration? Each has a different looking Event structure which changes where the keys are located.

Log the event ( `print(event)` will work just fine for a test run) then hit your endpoint and see what the event structure looks like.  That will tell you where you keys are supposed to be or if you have the wrong key value (Event structures dont get updated often but it does happen, and tutorial videos become out of date pretty quick)

The Event for a Lambda is (and indeed, all events in all of AWS) are just JSON objects. using python, that directly translates to a Dictionary so having the right key structure can be a little weird to figure out because documentation on what various Events look like in the AWS Sphere are scattered througout the documentation and hard to find.

I usually keep a lambda on my console that all it does is `print(event)` then hook it up to whatever trigger I am trying to use at the time so i can see what it looks like nice and clear.

Comment: API gateway is setup as proxy lambda integration